# Does shared hosting allow automatic file creation by php scripts?

Tags: file, hosting, creation

I have a website I've coded locally that creates new folders and files via PHP inside of a members/username directory when a user registers an account. Can a shared hosting plan accommodate this or will I need a VPS?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the limitations of the shared hosting... But if it runs PHP5.4+, it shouldn't be an issue since safe_mode have been removed from PHP5.4 and onwards, and this is the only thing that could have prevented the folders (and files inside it) creation.